# Conflicting Packages PersonManager App Java

Tags: java

So my problem is that when im trying to get a result for my Person manager app and for some reason after a bunch of trial and error i get a result like this

run:

> Welcome to the Person Manager
>
> Create customer or employee? (c/e): c
>
> First name: Steve Last name: Trevor Customer number: M10963
>
> You entered a new pkg8.pkg2.person.manager.Customer: Name: Steve
>   Trevor CustomerNumber: M10963
>
> Continue? (y/n):

now everything is alright up until I get "You entered a new pkg8.pkg2.person.manager.Customer:"
The pkg8.pkg2.person.manager. shouldn't be there.

here is my code

PersonManager.java

```
package pkg8.pkg2.person.manager;

/**
*
* @author Zachary
*/
public class PersonManager {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Person Manager");
    System.out.println("");
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        String type = Console.getString("Create customer or employee? (c/e): " , "c", "e");
        System.out.println("");

        String firstName = Console.getString("First name: ");
        String lastName = Console.getString("Last name: ");

        Person person;
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
            String customerNumber = Console.getString("Customer number: ");
            person = new Customer(firstName, lastName, customerNumber);

        }else{
            String ssn = Console.getString("SSN: ");
            person = new Employee(firstName, lastName, ssn);             
        }
        Class c = person.getClass();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("You entered a new " + c.getName() + ":");
        System.out.println(person.toString());
        System.out.println("");




        System.out.println("");            
        choice = Console.getString("Continue? (y/n): ", "y", "n");
        System.out.println();
     }
 }

}
```

Person.java

```
package pkg8.pkg2.person.manager;

/**
*
 * @author Zachary
*/
public class Person {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;


public Person(String first, String last){
firstName = first;
lastName = last;

}

public String getFirstName(){
return firstName;
}


public void setFirstName(String firstName){
this.firstName = firstName;
}


public String getLastName(){
return lastName;
}


public void setLastName(String lastName){
this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
return "Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName;
}

}
```

Customer.java

```
package pkg8.pkg2.person.manager;

/**
 *
 * @author Zachary
*/
public class Customer extends Person {

private String customerNumber;


public Customer(String first, String last, String number) {
    super(first, last);
    this.customerNumber = number;
}

public void setCustomerNumber(String number){
    this.customerNumber = number;
}

public String getCustomerNumber(){
    return customerNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String name = super.toString();
    return name + "\n" + "CustomerNumber: " + customerNumber;
}
}
```

Employee.java

```
package pkg8.pkg2.person.manager;

/**
*
 * @author Zachary
*/
public class Employee extends Person {

private String ssn;

public Employee(String first, String last, String ssn){
super(first, last);
this.ssn = ssn;
}

public String getSsn(){
return "xxx-xx-" + ssn.substring(ssn.length() - 4);    
}

public void setSsn(String ssn){
this.ssn = ssn;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
   String name = super.toString();
   return name + "\n" + "SSN: " + getSsn();
}
}
```

Console.java

```
package pkg8.pkg2.person.manager;


import java.util.*;

/**
*
* @author Zachary
*/
public class Console {
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String getString(String prompt) {
    String s = "";
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (!isValid) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        s = sc.nextLine();
        if (s.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Error! This entry is required. Try again.");
        } else {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

public static String getString(String prompt, String s1, String s2) {
    String s = "";
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (!isValid) {
        s = getString(prompt);
        if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase(s1) && !s.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)) {
            System.out.println("Error! Entry must be '" + s1 + "' or '" +
                    s2 + "'. Try again.");
        } else {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

public static int getInt(String prompt) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (!isValid) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            isValid = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine(); // discard any other data entered on the line
    }
    return i;
}

public static int getInt(String prompt, int min, int max) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (!isValid) {
        i = getInt(prompt);
        if (i <= min) {
            System.out.println(
            "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        } else if (i >= max) {
            System.out.println(
            "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
        } else {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

public static double getDouble(String prompt) {
    double d = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (!isValid) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            d = sc.nextDouble();
            isValid = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid number. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine(); // discard any other data entered on the line
    }
    return d;
}

public static double getDouble(String prompt, double min, double max) {
    double d = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (!isValid) {
        d = getDouble(prompt);
        if (d <= min) {
            System.out.println(
            "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        } else if (d >= max) {
            System.out.println(
            "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
        } else {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return d;
}
}
```

I understand that it is a conflicting package I just don't know how to fix it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect in its place? A different package name? And how do you know there is a conflict?

Comment: So im doing this for a class and the instructor said that it was conflicting packages after looking at all my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **read the documentation**, then you'll find that the javadoc of [`getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) states:

> If this class object represents a reference type that is not an array type then the ***binary name*** of the class is returned, as specified by *The Java™ Language Specification*.

JLS [13.1. The Form of a Binary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1) says:

> The class or interface must be named by its ***binary name***, which must meet the following constraints:
>
> - The binary name of a top level type ([§7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7)) is its ***canonical name*** ([§6.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7)).

JLS [6.7. Fully Qualified Names and Canonical Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) says:

> For every primitive type, named package, top level class, and top level interface, the ***canonical name*** is the same as the ***fully qualified name***.

> The ***fully qualified name*** of a top level class or top level interface that is declared in a named package consists of the **fully qualified name of the package, followed by ".", followed by the simple name of the class** or interface.

---

*In summary:* `getName()` returns the fully qualified name of the class.

If you don't want that, call [`getSimpleName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--).